# Isotope javascript js basic example not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I am trying to get Isotope javascript ) to work on a test page.

I am trying to get their example of Filtering with Isotope working. (Stackoverflow not allowing me to post a link as I'm new to posting on here...!)

I have copied their example HTML, CSS and vanilla  JS into a test page here on my domain: http://chrislydon.co.uk/testiso.php

(A php file because I want to test adding items from a MySQL DB once the basic thing is working!)

I think I have everything I need: reference to the Isotope JS in the head, their JS copied to between  tags - and their exact HTML (and CSS).

I am following the example which was labelled as "Vanilla JS" (as their other examples relies on JQuery (which I will implement eventually...))

I can't see what I'm doing wrong that means this verbatim copy of their example won't work....

(Tried it on different browsers - their examples work in them, but my copied example doesn't)

I'm OK with PHP/HTML but only done basic stuff in JS so perhaps I'm missing something terribly obvious!

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable code sample in your post.

Comment: His documentation is poorly written.  It's frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two main problems:

1) in the `<head>` of the document, your `<script>` tag is missing a `>`: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js‌​"</script>`

Change to:

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js‌​"></script>`

2)  If the above initializer runs in the `<head>` of the document, there will be no document available to query and `document.querySelector('.grid')` will return `null`.

Instead, put the script just before the `</body>` tag.

Working jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dptve3s6/1

Bonus:  You have a function called `myFunction` attached to a button's `onClick` event, but that function is not defined anywhere.  Define it, and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you - can't believe I missed the closing > on script tag! And the vanilla JS was copied directly from Isotope example.... odd that it didn't work. Your corrected JS did! (And putting it at the bottom, before </body> - useful to remember that one!) Thanks

Comment: @ChrisLydon I've updated my answer since I did not realize that the isotope JS library supports a selector string in addition to a DOM element as the constructor's first argument.  Therefore, there were only two problems.  See the updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dptve3s6/1

Comment: Thanks, yes your edited answer still works on my test site. I am trying to implement in a Joomla environment and it's not playing ball with with Jquery or without. (https://www.buffalobrownies.com/?view=article&id=269) - http://stackoverflow.com/q/43962392/8006962