# Integrating Isotope js on Joomla 1.5 site

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla1.5, jquery-isotope

I am trying to integrate Isotope JS on Joomla 1.5 site. (I know it's old Joomla!)

https://www.buffalobrownies.com/?view=article&id=269

I got the code working fine on a test page on that domain (but outside of Joomla).

Inside Joomla, neither the JQuery nor vanilla JS seems to trigger.

With JQuery trigger code on, I get this error on Chrome Console:

*Cannot read property 'isotope' of null*

(With the vanilla JS script turned on I get a bunch of OTHER errors......)

So I'm guessing there is something wrong with the reference to $ but I'm not clued up enough to know what it is...

Any thoughts out there? Thanks for your help

(I have Jquery linked high up in the `<head>`, then Isotope JS link just after, then the isotope trigger JS before the bottom `</body>` tag)

Chris

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered that it was Mootools in Joomla 1.5 that was causing the conflict.
(I just had to start taking lines of code out, one by one, until I found the one that made the difference).

I managed to find some code online that turned Mootools off for the front end, but kept it on for the back end.

Now I've managed to get the Isotope script working in my example. Now I just need to get it working with live data!